# Competitive: match suddenly ends without warning

Tags: overwatch

I was in the middle of a competitive match, when all of a sudden, around four people left at the same time. Not sure if they were on my team or not, but I assume those were on the enemy team since they were losing badly. A few seconds after the disconnects, I'm suddenly back on the main menu myself, with no explanation as to what just happened. No message, no warning.

At first, I thought I disconnected, but I wasn't logged out (I still had internet) and the "Play" button didn't say "Rejoin", so I assume the whole competitive match was just... finished? Usually, when the other team leaves, you still go through the usual endgame stuff: the victory screen, POTG and endgame cards. This time however, I was just sent straight to the main menu.

I checked to see if I was maybe penalized or something, but everything seems fine. Unfortunately, I don't know if it registered a win, but it seems like I got points instead of losing them. Or maybe nothing happened? I have no idea if that match counted as a win or not because of its abrupt ending.

What happened here?

Comment: This also occasionally happens in quick play - was there a message in chat similar to "Server encountered an error, now closing"?

Comment: @MageXy Nope, nothing at all.

Comment: The game won't continue without "enough" players. It will tolerate 1 or 2 leavers and force everyone else to keep playing anyway. I'm only guessing here, but they still want to allow the "winning" team to get credit for the effort they put in to "get" the other team to quit, without punishing too much the teammates that were abandoned by the quitter. However with too many players leaving, it's just sort of pointless, so it just ends the game. I am putting this as a comment because I cannot verify or test that, but I've had it happen before with 3+ leavers on enemy team.

Comment: @ZealousHypocrites That literally never happened to me before. The match just continues, even if there is only one guy left on the other team. Then, out of pity, most of my teams offer to give the last remaining enemy the Lucio achievement, so they get something out of it at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take this with a grain of salt, but what you describe sounds very much like one or more players on the enemy team have discovered a bug in the game that allows them to nullify the match and possibly not acquire a loss.

I've had competitive games where the enemy team had only one player on their side, so it wasn't a game-design feature that happened to you.

I'd check with the battle.net forums and report the issue there.

Comment: This was my thought as well.  Similar bugs get exploited all the time in literally every competitive game.